# Value animator not starting from previous value

Tags: java, android, android-animation

```
public void startAnimation() {


        ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(oldmSweepAngle, mEndAngle);
        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                ProgressCircle.this.mSweepAngle = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                   ProgressCircle.this.invalidate();
            }
        });
        anim.setDuration(500);
        anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        anim.start();

    }

}
```

I am trying to create a progressive Circle that changes it Progress value at each Bluetooth Input from the user. The Progress value updates the msEndangle and hence the Progress circle is incremented or decremented using start Animation. My Problem is that the animator is not updating the arc rather it restarts from 0 everytime a new mEndangle/ProgressValue arrives. I mean if 1st progressValue is 50 and 2nd Progress value is 55 the animator should start animating from 50 and increase to 55 while 0 to 50 remains colored. But it starts animating from 0 to 55. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The Code finally worked by declaring the mSweepAngle as static. i was able to then store the previous value of mSweepangle in oldmSweepangle and so change the way it animates.